# if more than one control using the same strip menu , how to determine which called it

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, controls

im having 24 controls(pictureboxes) using the same strip menu, on the click event of any item in that strip menu i would want to know which control that used this strip menu item
for instance

```
private void getInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

how to determine which control from the 24 controls that's using this menu
if it's not possible, is there any way around that to achieve the same purpose ? (to have all the controls sharing the same code without having 24 menu for the 24 controls with writing the code in all of them)

thanks and have a wonderful day

edit: for sake of clarification here is a rephrase of the problem
"a groupbox with 24 pictureboxes inside, all sharing same strip menu, i would want to determine which picturebox clicked the strip menu item so i can use that in the code to do something with the name of control (matching it with a keyvaluepair list)"
here is a picture
[image]

all i want to know which picturebox of those had clicked getinfo, that's it

Comment: Track a "selection" property relating to which of the 24 is "active", changing it as a different one receives focus.  Let the menu access the member.

Comment: i think that would be my last option, but lets see if there is a decent one first

Comment: It would be helpful for you to elaborate on this:  "im having 24 controls(pictureboxes) using the same strip menu".  How does this menu know anything about the picture boxes (or vice versa)?

Comment: sure, ill add that, maybe it makes more sense

Comment: I see you added my question to your question.  I was actually suggesting that you explain to us how the relationship works.  But if you don't know how they relate, then the suggestion I made is likely your only option.  The item you are clicking has no knowledge of the thing you want to show info for.  Therefore, you must track that separately so that the menu item/toolstrip item can know what to do.

Comment: sorry i understood that wrong, a groupbox with 24 pictureboxes inside, all sharing same strip menu, i would want to determine which picturebox clicked the strip menu item so i can use that in the code to do something with the name of control (matching it with a keyvaluepair list)

Comment: @AndrewRober what's `strip menu`? If you don't make it clear, your problem is still stuck.

Comment: "which picturebox clicked the strip menu item"  <-- how does that work?  Show some code please.  Is it automated somehow, or do you mean _it had focus_ and the user clicked a menu item?

Comment: i've added a picture , it's ContextMenuStrip and the picture would explain it better, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some replies, it's clear that you want to get the control clicking on which the `ContextMenuStrip` is popped up. Simply you can use the `SourceControl` property to get that control.

```
private void getInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  PictureBox pb = contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl as PictureBox;
}
```

Comment: im sorry but the sender is the menu strip itself and the e.clickeditem is the item inside the menu strip itself and not the control on the form

Comment: @AndrewRober of course `e.ClickedItem` is one of the items on the `ToolStrip`, I don't get your problem well. You should call the **exact type name** of your menu strip, `ContextMenuStrip`, `MenuStrip`, or anything else?

Comment: for sake of clarification here is a rephrase of the problem "a groupbox with 24 pictureboxes inside, all sharing same strip menu, i would want to determine which picturebox clicked the strip menu item so i can use that in the code to do something with the name of control (matching it with a keyvaluepair list)"

Comment: @AndrewRober I asked you to make it clearer on the exact type name of `strip menu`, it's important to know it, for example, I guess it's `ContextMenuStrip`?

Comment: yeah , sorry english isn't my main language, and yes it's ContextMenuStrip

Comment: finally! , thank you alot for bearing with me and sorry for the misunderstanding